# convert logical gates to cnf python

Tags: python, sat, cnf

i have an object-oriented logical circuit that's created from gate objects
(similar to the second example here:

http://www.openbookproject.net/books/pythonds/Introduction/ObjectOrientedProgramminginPythonDefiningClasses.html )

I need to represent the circuit as CNF:
for example https://ibb.co/W2Z4M3y

is there any library that can do it?
or any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

There's two libraries:

[Sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/logic.html) which has a `to_cnf` function as well as a `to_dnf` function.

Similiarly there's
[PyEDA](https://pyeda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which also has both the `to_cnf` and `to_dnf` function.

You should check both the documentations to see which one fits your need.

You can use [Pysathq](https://pysathq.github.io/docs/html/api/formula.html) to convert the text to DIMACS CNF format

Comment: any idea how can i convert Sympy output into DIMCAS CNF?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Look at the last link.